# How to restrict rake routes output to URI Pattern and Controller#action columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, awk, routes, rake

In my rails 4.x app on a Mac, I call rake routes, and I get the following output:

**Raw output (without awk):**

```
> bundle exec rake routes
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern    Controller#Action                                                  
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)           devise/sessions#new                                       
                 PATCH  /users/password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
new_api_user_session GET    /api/auth/sign_in(.:format)    devise_token_auth/sessions#new {:format=>:json}
```

I want to call rake routes, but output only the last two columns (URI Pattern and Controller#action). It is also a fact that the last two columns begin with a '/', while the first two columns never have a '/'.

**Desired output:**

```
> bundle exec rake routes | awk 'something'
URI Pattern    Controller#Action                                                  
/users/sign_in(.:format)           devise/sessions#new                                       
/users/password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
/api/auth/sign_in(.:format)    devise_token_auth/sessions#new {:format=>:json}
```

I tried these approaches:

**Approach 1:**

```
> bundle exec rake routes | awk '{print $(NF-1),"\t",$NF}'
Pattern      Controller#Action
/users/sign_in(.:format)           devise/sessions#new                                       
/users/password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
devise_token_auth/sessions#new     {:format=>:json}
```

The first two rows (/users/sign_in and /users/password) work fine, but the third one treats devise_token_auth/sessions#new and {:format =>:json} to be separate columns, due to default field separator being space. Also, for the same reason, the header row chopped out the word URI from URI Pattern.

**Approach 2:**

```
> bundle exec rake routes | awk '{$1=""; $2=""; print}'
URI Pattern Controller#Action
/users/sign_in(.:format)           devise/sessions#new                                       
devise/passwords#update
/api/auth/sign_in(.:format)    devise_token_auth/sessions#new {:format=>:json}
```

In the second approach, it works fine for the first (/users/sign_in) and third (/api/auth/sign_in) rows, but it is messed up in the second row, because there is a blank first (prefix) column.

**Approach 3:**

I also looked for a filter switch on rake routes, (Like the top command has -stats)? but in [the routes rakefile](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks/routes.rake), I couldn't find any such option.

**Approach 4:**

The following approach works, but it uses a different fact about the data - that we need all the content beginning with the first '/':

```
# rake_awk


#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{   
  search="/";
  n=split($0,array,search);
  if(n == 1) {
   print "\n", $3, $4, "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", $5, "\n";
  }
  else {
    for (i=2;i<=n;i++) {
        if (i < n) {
          printf("/%s", array[i]);
        }
        else {
          printf("/%s\n", array[i]);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And from the command line:

```
> bundle exec rake routes | /path/to/rake_awk

URI Pattern                         Controller#Action

/users/sign_in(.:format)           devise/sessions#new                                       
/users/password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
/api/auth/sign_in(.:format)        devise_token_auth/sessions#new {:format=>:json}
```

Comment: @EdMorton I have updated the question with the baseline and more details - Ruby on rails (a web app framework) has a rake ('ruby make') that has a common rakefile (analogous to makefile) called routes. The rake routes command outputs a bunch of web routes in my web app. The first snippet shows the baseline output, I am trying to print only the last two columns of output. See the updated question for details.

Comment: it helps to frame your Q as, A. sample input data, B/ required output from same data, C. current output. D. Current best guess at coded solution, E.Any error messages being generated. ### You can also include any other information that will help users to replicate your problem in their environment and comments about why you are using the approach currently in your code. As is, this info may be there, but it is hard to "parse" the info in your Q. Good luck.!

Comment: @shellter - I have updated the question with most of these details.

Comment: Do you know about http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-15 ? Good luck.

Comment: @EdMorton I just told you what rake is - but it doesn't matter for an awk person (the fact that I tagged it with ruby-on-rails and rake make it relevant to a rails person) - there is a command that prints the first output. I want just the two last columns of that output to be printed - I tried two awk based approaches and one rake based approach, none of which gave me the desired output. How do i get the desired output? I am also updating the question to describe the desired output.

Comment: @shellter - the link seems useful. I have updated the question further to provide all required details.

Comment: @EdMorton Fixed the formatting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your latest requirements and the answer you posted, this may be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 { print $3, $4 "\t" $5; next }
{ sub("[^/]+",""); sub(/ +/,"\t"); print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
URI Pattern     Controller#Action
/users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#new
/users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#update
/api/auth/sign_in(.:format)     devise_token_auth/sessions#new {:format=>:json}

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s $'\t' -t
URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
/users/sign_in(.:format)     devise/sessions#new
/users/password(.:format)    devise/passwords#update
/api/auth/sign_in(.:format)  devise_token_auth/sessions#new {:format=>:json}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your solution above, but it does not work. Perhaps it is my inability to articulate the exact format in more rigorous terms. I went with a simpler string based approach - based on the fact that I needed all the content beyond the first occurrence of '/' to be outputted - see approach 4 in the question (will update it in a second).

Comment: I have 175 rows, most of which fall into the above three example patterns. When I ran your second (visually aligned) awk command above, the line in the raw input which looks like this: (there are > 20 spaces in the beginning, which I cannot format as code with backticks) - `                       DELETE /users(.:format)                                                devise/registrations#destroy` just returns `devise/registrations#destroy` instead of `/users(.:format)                                                devise/registrations#destroy` (there are no tabs in the input row)

Comment: Trouble is, it is not my input :-) - it is the output of rake, and I cannot include the entire output, because some of it is not public. I could include this example, but another one might break. I still don't know how the violating line in my last comment is different from the second line in my question example. But when I run your script, the question line outputs fine, but the comment line does not. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Anand I edited my answer to show a solution given what you've now told us.

Answer (score 3):

Awk may be be a little awkward. It works, but you can query the routes directly, which will be much faster than waiting for `rake` to run. Here is how to do it in Rails 5.

> As a guide, take a look at the source code for `rake routes`:
>
> https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b5db73076914e7103466bd76bec785cbcfe88875/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/inspector.rb#L104

```
all_routes = Rails.application.routes.routes

routes = all_routes.map do |route|
  ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteWrapper.new(route)
end

routes.reject!(&:internal?)

results = routes.map do |route|
  { name: route.name,
    verb: route.verb,
    path: route.path,
    reqs: route.reqs }
end

puts results.map{|r| "#{r[:path]}, #{r[:reqs]}"}.join("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using the updated data that the required output starts with a '/'. Thanks to shellter's link in the question comments (I learnt a lot about awk today from Ed Morton and shellter's comments):

```
# rake_awk

#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{   
  search="/";
  n=split($0,array,search);
  if(n == 1) {
   print "\n", $3, $4, "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", $5, "\n";
  }
  else {
    for (i=2;i<=n;i++) {
        if (i < n) {
          printf("/%s", array[i]);
        }
        else {
          printf("/%s\n", array[i]);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And from the command line:

```
> bundle exec rake routes | /path/to/rake_awk

URI Pattern                         Controller#Action

/users/sign_in(.:format)           devise/sessions#new                                       
/users/password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
/api/auth/sign_in(.:format)        devise_token_auth/sessions#new {:format=>:json}
```

Comment: To print everything from the first `/` on is just `{sub("^[^/]+/",""); print}`. No need for splits, loops, etc. The way to write the loop you wrote, if it were needed, is just `for (i=2;i<=n;i++) printf "/%s%s", array[i], (i<n?"":ORS)`. With `print "\n", $3, $4, "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", $5, "\n";` you're adding presumably undesirable leading/trailing blank lines before/after that line and blank chars around the tabs - just make it `print $3, $4 "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" $5` (note the removed commas before/after the tabs).

Comment: @EdMorton That is extremely useful information. Thanks!